# Проверка существования переменной без учета регистра имени переменной

Tags: javascript

Припустим есть переменная
var helLo=12;
а может быть и такое var hEllo=90;
Как узнать что переменная существует/имееет значение,без учета регистра?

```
   var hello=(typeof hello=='undefined') ? 0 :hello
```

Даже не знаю зачем такое может понадобится..

Comment: Интересная задача. Можно перебрать все возможные варианты капитализации, но это какое-то уж слишком грубое решение.

Comment: Перибирать window через for...in +регулярка имени?А как же локальные переменные?

Comment: Как уже было подмечено, перебирать все переменные через for in, каждую из которых переводить в нижний регистр и сравнивать с просто hello. При совпадении, вытаскивать оригинальное название. ( надо продумать механизм сохранения перебираемых переменных в изначальном виде, чтоб узнать какая она именна heLlo или heLLO и т.д ). P.S. Не кидайтесь помидорами, я бы так начал свою попытку. P.P.S. Можно же как-то имя переменной перевести в нижний регистр или я что-то путаю?

Comment: toLowerCase();

Comment: @Genson, нет, вы все правильно думаете, только вот я тоже не понят зачем такое может понадобиться :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](http://jsfiddle.net/upNps/):

```
function isNameDefined(name)
{
    var s = "typeof " + name + " === \"undefined\"";
    return !eval(s);
}

function getDefinedNames(proto)
{
    var result = [];
    var l = proto.length;
    var maxsubset = 1 << l;
    for (var subset = 0; subset < maxsubset; subset++) // check all subsets
    {
        var name = "";
        for (var pos = 0; pos < l; pos++)
        {
            var c = proto.charAt(pos);
            if ((subset & (1 << pos)) !== 0)
                c = c.toUpperCase();
            name = name + c;
        }
        if (isNameDefined(name))
            result.push(name);
    }
    return result;
}

// пример использования:

var proto = "hello";

// define some vars:

var hEllO = 0;
var HEllo = "hello!";

var names = getDefinedNames(proto);
alert("defined names: " + names.join());
```

Работает по идее и для локальных переменных. Не уверен, сработает ли в другом контексте.

Comment: Спасибо.Прочитаю только про битовые операции.

Comment: @zloctb: битовые операции нужны для перечисления всех подмножеств данного множества. Таким образом алгоритм выбирает, какие буквы превращать в заглавные.